# rigorous definition of maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading the *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*, written by Bishop. On page 27, the parameter of Guassian distribution $\mu$ can be regarded as 
$$\mu_{\text{ML}}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_1^N x_n$$
The $x_n$ are observed value, and they are real. However, author also see them as a random variables. Is there any probability theory to explain the contradiction.
Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's better to write $\mu_{\text{ML}}$ as $\hat{\mu}_{\text{ML}}$ to highlight it is an estimator rather a parameter --- this is a convention used extensively in statistics (in the following I will denote it by $\hat{\mu}$ for simplicity).

To answer your question, depending on the purposes of analysis, $\hat{\mu}$ can be treated as either random variable (function) or observed value (real number).

If the purpose is to explore the statistical/mathematical properties, such as compute its mean/variance, derive its asymptotic distribution, etc, we should treat $\hat{\mu}$ as a random variable, under which case it's better to use capital case lettersto denote the sample and write
$$\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^N X_n,$$
and in some literature $\hat{\mu}$ is called an **estimator** in that it is its distributional property instead of its numerical value is of our primary interest. This perspective is mostly taken in mathematical/theoretical statistics course/literature.

If the purpose is to analyze a particular data set and draw some empirical conclusion, $\hat{\mu}$ is treated as observed value, under which case it's more conventional to denote sample by lower case letters and write
$$\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^N x_n,$$
and sometimes $\hat{\mu}$ is referred as an **estimate**. This perspective is mostly taken in applied statistics and data mining.

The underlying reason for such distinction lies in whether the sample $S = \{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N\}$ has been observed/obtained. Before the observation/experimentation has been made to $S$, the only sensible way to deal with $S$ is to view it as a collection of random variables, consequently, all we can do with it and its function (such as $\hat{\mu}$ in this example) is to discuss mathematical properties under some assumptions. If the observation/experimentation has been made to $S$, the numerical values of $S$ (called *realization* of $S$) is available to us, under which we can conduct any reasonable data analysis and make statistical inference (which, of course, relies on the theoretical properties of its corresponding estimator).

Comment: So in maximum likelihood estimation, $\mu$ is an estimator or an estimate? Thx.

Comment: As I answered, it can be both, depending on what perspective you take.

Comment: In maximum likelihood estimation, we maximize the value of the product of  density. However, the density is neither a random value nor an obeserved value?

Comment: When you wrote $f(X_i; \mu) \text{ or } f(x_i; \mu), i = 1, 2, \ldots$,, you treat it as random variables or numerical values.